# I cannot make a sample request with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I just installed Alamofire 3.0 with swift 2.2 and xcode 7.3.1

When I try to make the request as in the example at:

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

xcode says this:

[image: Expected Declaration]

I can not understand why

Comment: The Alamofire code is not in a function, it's "floating". You can't put code like that anywhere you want.

Comment: Put your code in ViewDidLoad()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your request outside a function. Put it inside a `function` or in `viewDidLoad` and it will work for you.

Comment: when i put it inside viewDidLoad i have another error: cannot invoke 'request' with an argument list of type '(string)'

Comment: You need to add the request body to your request, checkout the documentation of how to do that.